# xcode IOS swift NSURLConnection works slow

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm trying to get information from my API and show it on APP, everything is fine except that slow printing on view. After i got JSON information from my API it stucks for ±5-8 secs.

There is my function for async post:

```
class func postAsync(post :NSString, def: Bool = true, completionHandler: ((AnyObject?, NSError?) -> Void)) {

    var post_url : NSString

        /* SOME CODE */

    post_url = post

    let jsonData = NSDictionary();

    var postData:NSData = post_url.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!

    var postLength:NSString = String( postData.length )

    let cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: cachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 2.0)

    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = postData
    request.setValue(postLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")


    var reponseError: NSError?
    var response: NSURLResponse?

    var urlData: NSData? = nil

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler: { (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if (error != nil) {
            completionHandler(nil, error)
            println("API error: \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
        var jsonError:NSError?

        let jsonData:NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &jsonError) as NSDictionary
        if (jsonError != nil) {
            println("Error parsing json: \(jsonError)")
            completionHandler(nil, jsonError)
        }
        else {

            ... error ...

            completionHandler(jsonData, nil)

        }
    })

}
```

This is how i call it:

```
        WebReq.postAsync("default", def: true) { (data, error) -> Void in
        if let er = error {
            println("\(er)")
        }

        if let arr = data?["arr"] as? NSArray {
            for (index,album) in enumerate(arr) {

                var position = CGRect(x: 0, y: index*21, width: 90, height: 20)
                var label = UILabel(frame: position)
                label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
                label.text = album["text"] as? NSString
                self.view.addSubview(label)

            }
        }
    }
```

And results prints after 5-8 secs. If I do synchronized then hangs my whole app for a little bit shorter time like 2-5 secs

If do println() on that place where I'm trying to create UILabel, then it appears instantly after I get and parse my info.

Any suggestions? I've no idea where is the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have instructed `sendAsynchronousRequest` to use a background operation queue for the completion block (you instantiated a new `NSOperationQueue()`). Therefore, you are trying to do UI updates from background thread. But UI updates must happen on the main thread.

Either

1. Specify main queue in the `sendAsynchronousRequest` call:

   ```
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { response, data, error in
        ...
    )
   ```

   or
2. Manually dispatch the UI updates back to the main queue

   ```
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue()) { response, data, error in
        // do stuff in background queue

        // when ready to update model/UI dispatch that to main queue
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            ...
        } 
    )
   ```

   or

   ```
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue()) { response, data, error in
        // do stuff in background queue

        // when ready to update model/UI dispatch that to main queue
        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock { 
            ...
        } 
    )
   ```

Comment: you know I love you ;) saved my day